# Replacing values in a column based on condition of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have an airline dataset and in one month the airport codes are coded differently.  I found a source to correct it, but can't seem to get it to work.

```
airline_df = pd.DataFrame({'airport':['ORD', 'LAS', 'BOS', 10721, 12889]})

airport_code = pd.DataFrame({'airport':['BOS', 'LAS', 'ORD'], 'airport_code':[10721, 12889, 13930]}
```

I also created a dictionary of the code:airport using

```
code_dict = airport_codes.set_index('airport_code').to_dict()['airport']
```

I am trying to replace all the airport values that are numbers with the airport name.

Comment: did you try replace?

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

Comment: or `map` + `fillna`: `airline_df.airport.map(code_dict).fillna(airline_df.airport)`